# lapply to recursive list gives incorrect dimensions

Tags: r

I have a recursive list that I want to perform some functions on.

example:

```
subset_list<-list(A=list(kan=data.frame(corr=seq(1,10),Lib=rep("Kan",times=10),pheno1=seq(11,20),pheno2=seq(20,11)),Cm=data.frame(corr=seq(1,10),Lib=rep("Cm",times=10),pheno1=seq(1,10),pheno2=seq(10,1)),all=data.frame(corr=seq(1,20),Lib=rep("AQ",times=20),pheno1=seq(1,20),pheno2=seq(20,1))),B=list(kan=data.frame(corr=seq(1,10),Lib=rep("Kan",times=10),pheno1=seq(11,20),pheno2=seq(20,11)),Cm=data.frame(corr=seq(10,20),Lib=rep("Cm",times=11),pheno1=seq(10,20),pheno2=seq(20,10)),all=data.frame(corr=seq(20,40),Lib=rep('AQ',times=21),pheno1=seq(0,20),pheno2=seq(20,0))))
```

By reading previous posts I came up with this solution to find the density for each of the sublists.  It is working although it seems a bit awkward to me.

```
density_subset_list<-lapply(subset_list,function(x) lapply(lapply(x,'[[','corr'),density))
```

However, my next function is subsetting based on 2 columns and I can't figure out how to do this.  Below is my attempt, but it results in a list of 3 (Kan, Cm, all - the internal lists) as opposed to 2 (A,B the 1st level of lists).

```
for (i in 1:length(subset_list)){
    subset_list_excLowPheno<-lapply(subset_list[[i]],function(x) subset(x,x$pheno1 > 10 & x$pheno2 > 10 ))
}
```

Any advice on methods for applying these functions to these recursive lists is welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Hard to reproduce, since `INTlist` and `corr` are not found in your example.

Comment: sorry, I edited it, INTlist was supposed to say subset_list (2 lists I have of the same dimension), and corr is found in my example, it is a variable within the dataframes

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you want to do. Can you show us your desired output? Also your second line can be simplified using `density_subset_list <- lapply(subset_list, lapply, function(x) density(x[, 'corr']))`